# Blank screen on Mobile Device with Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm working with Sencha Touch trying to create a mobile Wordpress theme for a website. At the moment I'm  testing the code from the following this [tutorial](http://superdit.com/2011/09/24/create-simple-wordpress-mobile-theme-using-sencha-touch-part-1/)

Everything runs fine on my desktop browser. But when I access the site from my mobile device (iPhone or Android), I just get a blank screen.

***UPDATE***

Below is the code in `index.php`, on my mobile device all I see is `THIS IS A TEST`, whereas on my desktop browser `THIS IS A TEST` appears and then the JS loads.

```
<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/senchatouch/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>

<div id="sencha-app">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Place your view files here -->
    <div id="sencha-views">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/views/Viewport.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/views/Post/Index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/views/Post/Single.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/views/Post/Comment.js"></script>
    </div>

    <!-- Place your model files here -->
    <div id="sencha-models">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/models/Post.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/models/Comment.js"></script>
    </div>

    <!-- Place your controller files here -->
    <div id="sencha-controllers">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(" template_url "); ?>/app/controllers/Post.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also downloaded the Kitchen Sink from the Sencha Touch website and it runs with no issues on both mobile devices.

So I'm not sure whats going on or where to start looking, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any javascript error on chromes developer tools?

Comment: Ykartal, there are no errors in Chromes dev tools.

Comment: Could you give a link to see blank page on the internet?

Comment: Can you open the Developer menu on the iPhone, and check what the error you are gettin in the iPhone console. Post it here and we can help.